# ActiveAdmin custom select filter dropdown names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, filter, activeadmin

For a user model I have a filter to check the booking status of a user which is represented by an integer value (0, 1, or 2).

The filter on the User ActiveAdmin index page is achieved with the following code:

```
  filter :booking_status, as: :select
```

However this results in the dropdown options being either 0, 1, or 2.

I would prefer if I could name them myself to something like "Incomplete", "Pending", and "Confirmed" when the admin user is selecting them from the dropdown.

[image]

Is there any way of doing this without changing how the booking_status is represented in the model?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Assuming `booking_status` is an enum field in your model, you can use:

`filter :booking_status, as: :select, collection: ModelName.booking_statuses`

If `booking_status` is not an enum field, you can pass a regular hash to the `collection` option, something like:

`filter :booking_status, as: :select, collection: {'Incomplete' => 0, 'Pending' => 1, 'Complete' => 2}`